# Error while running R script in taskscheduleR, but everything works well while running code in R Studio

Tags: r

So I have an R script which do some basic data analysis, then save a csv file, jpegs and text file. I ran the scheduling in the add-in in R-studio. The error code I'm getting is:

```
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: write.csv -> eval.parent -> eval -> eval -> write.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '2021-07-14sudanpost.csv': Permission denied
Execution halted
```

I'm using the following function to save a dataframe as csv. They work while running in R-Studio, but I'm guessing this is where the above error occurs while using taskscheduleR.

```
csvname <- as.character(Sys.Date())
csvname2 <- paste0(csvname, "sudanpost.csv")
write.csv(sudan_post, csvname2)
```

I am running the script daily and am using Sys.Date() to differentiate the names. Not sure if it's "best practice". The script should also save some jpeg files, although I haven't get to that point yet. Any insight on if it would work?

```
jpegname <- paste0(csvname, "headlines_word_frequency.jpeg")
jpeg(jpegname)
bar <- barplot(dtm_d[1:10,]$freq, las = 2, names.arg = dtm_d[1:10,]$word,
        col ="steelblue", main ="Top 10 most frequent words",
        ylab = "Word frequencies")
dev.off()
```

Comment: What are you setting as the rscript repo location in the add-in? It looks like you don't have permission to write to that directory.

Comment: If you have your csv. opened in the background R will give you usually the same error you describe. Are you sure you have the files closed?